# Does a Kafka Consumer default batch size?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Does Kafka provide a default batch size for reading messages from a topic? I have the following code that is reading messages from a topic.

```
  while (true) {
        final ConsumerRecords<String, User> consumerRecords =
                consumer.poll(500));
        if (consumerRecords.count() == 0) {
            noRecordsCount++;
            if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
            else continue;
        }
        consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            User user = record.value();
            userArray.add(user);
        });

        insertInBatch(user)
        consumer.commitAsync();
    }
    consumer.close();
```

In the insertInBatch method, I persist data to a database. This method is getting called every 500 records, even though I haven't specified any batch size in creating the Consumer. 
I don't think there's anything special about the way I'm creating it. Using Avro for the messages, but I don't think that's significant(?)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

    props.put("key.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.serializer",KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("schema.registry","http://localhost:8081");
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there's a default `max.poll.records`

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

If you are inserting to a database, though, you'd be better off using Kafka Connect than writing a consumer with apparently no error handling (yet?)

Comment: Note that `max.poll.records` is only applied on the consumer side. Under the cover, the size of batches fetched from brokers is controlled by `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.bytes`.

Comment: I would definitely NOT recommend the Connect JDBC sink. It requires a schema which is either Avro or a schema on EACH message (bloat!). Doesn't support schemas in the .properties file. Also doesn't support pulling columns from the key. Many other issues as well.

Comment: I'd use the batch listener in Kafka Spring. Works great and has all the kinks ironed out.

Comment: @Sledge And what data format do you use? Java serializables? JSON? Avro is less bloated than that, and no there's a number on each message, not a whole schema ... And SMTs do allow pulling columns from the key. Sounds like you've not thoroughly explored the Connect API

Comment: @cricket_007 Since you mentioned writing to a DB through Kafka Connect, I assumed you were referring to the JDBC sink connector, no? That requires a schema. EITHER with json serdes w/ schema enabled for every message, or the lighter weight Avro. The JDBC sink also has a limitation where it'll only allow you to pull from the key for the PK (which prevents you from having dupes). In my case I wanted the key as a column, but not as PK. Yes, I could probably do stuff with yet another SMT. Or just use a batch listener where the batching is 90% done already.

Comment: @cricket_007 The schema (registry) is the biggest nuisance with the JDBC sink. I haven't needed it anywhere else yet. I use the spool dir and that one supports a schema in the .properties which I would have done to get the JDBC sink to work, but they don't support that.

Comment: @Sledge It's not required. Feel free to use Protobuf converter by BlueApron which can give a schema file on the properties file. Feel free to open a Github JIRA to start a discussion or use this https://github.com/farmdawgnation/registryless-avro-converter/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @cricket_007 Hmmm... interesting... I'll take a look at that. Thanks.